# how to send a get request to bit torrent tracker

Tags: c, get, bittorrent

I am trying to implement a bit torrent client.

The first step is decode the torrent file, which I did and here is result:

```
d8:announce36:http://tracker.mininova.org/announce7:comment41:Auto-generated
torrent by Mininova.org CD13:creation
datei1212041255e4:infod5:filesld6:lengthi291e4:pathl27:Distributed by
Mininova.txteed6:lengthi199784e4:pathl19:the cs
song.mp3.mp3eee4:name33:The Counter Strike Song version 212:piece
lengthi1048576e6:pieces20:è¶¬oîdÏ9`•×=ü¼e6:locale2:en5:title33:The
Counter Strike Song version 2e.
```

The second step is sending a HTTP GET request to the tracker's
announce URL with "?" and the following parameters (encoded as above)
appended. This is the part I am struck on. I have been researching how
to send HTTP GET in C; it seem you need first set up a TCP socket and
connect to the tracker server first. I have been doing this:

```
if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
{
    printf("fail create socket");
    return 0;
}
char *path = “tracker.mininova.org/announce7”;
struct hostent *hp = gethostbyname(path);
memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
&servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = ((struct sockaddr_in*)(res->ai_addr))->sin_addr.s_addr;
servAddr.sin_port   = htons(portNum);
```

However, `gethostbyname` keep returning `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `gethostbyname` on a string that's not just a domain, `"tracker.mininova.org/announce7"`. You need to be calling it on just the domain, `"tracker.mininova.org"`. You could check the `h_errno` value to figure this out.

However, the use of `gethostbyname` and related functions should be replaced by use of `getaddrinfo` anyway (which has the same limitations, but will provide better results).